# How to copy folder and renaming it with incrementing number + user input

Tags: batch-file, files-folders

I want to create a batch file that copies a folder (containing subfolders and files) and renames the folder with "S21-999-CASENUMBER CASENAME"

The `Casenumber` is incrementing from 001 based on the last created folder.
The `Casename` is user input

Example

```
S21-999-001 MBI
S21-999-002 MBI
S21-999-003 Vugger
.......
```

But when I run it I get the following result

```
S21-999-001 MBI
S21-999-001 Vugger
S21-999-002 MBI
```

Can anyone help me with spotting the error in my file? :)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "baseName=S21-999-"
set "n=0"
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  '2^>nul dir /b /ad "%baseName%*."^|findstr /xri "%baseName%[0-9]*"'
) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  set "name=!name:*%baseName%=!"
  if !name! gtr !n! set "n=!name!"
)
set /p "m=Indtast Sagsnavn: "
set /a "n=+1"
xcopy "Q:\10 - Dokumentation\9 - Skabeloner\Sagsmappestruktur\REV. 7" "%baseName%"%n%" %m%" /s /e /i /y
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What do the folders look like before?